# Node/express backend crashing when calling the API (MERN stack)

Tags: node.js, express, mern

Router:

```
router.route('/allmovies/:searchtext').get(moviesCtrl.getMovieBySearchText);
```

Controller:

```
const getMovieBySearchText = async (req, res) => {
    const searchText = req.params.searchtext;
    const searchedMovies = await Movies.find({ $text: { $search: searchText } }).limit(10).sort({ score: { $meta: "textScore" } });
    if (!searchedMovies) return res.status(204).json({'message': 'No movie found.'});
    res.json(searchedMovies);
}
```

When I do a search from my frontend, it puts the params in the URL, which the backend grabs. If the search is blank, it will crash the backend server. I can subvert this by setting up a default get for `'/allmovies/'`. I'm just trying to better understand why this happens, or if there is a better way to handle this. I looked at express validator, but that only made sense for posting data, not getting. Yes, the frontend can be validated, but there are ways around that, and the server won't be safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not call an endpoint without passing its parameters, I think the crash is because another endpoint will be called if you don't pass the `searchtext`.
I suggest to use a `query` instead:

```
/allmovies?searchtext=anything
```

And also it is better to use an `if` statement and if `searchText` was empty, run your query without any search.

Comment: The front end URL looks like ```http://localhost:3000/movielist?s=hello``` which is what ```:searchtext``` becomes on the backend. I tried to do an ```if``` statement for ```searchtext``` but it crashes immediately. I think you're right about the endpoint though. I think it expects that to exist, and if it doesn't, explodes.